# Change font property for label in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, fonts

I have a table with 10 cells. I know how to change the font, size, etc. in all cells. But I need to change the font only in the 3rd cell. How can i do this ?

Comment: In your `cellForRowAt` function set your font according to the indexPath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
 if indexPath.row == 2 && indexPath.section == yoursection {
       cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
  } else {
       cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 100)
  }
```

Comment: So far this has not worked. I think the reason for this is because I have several sections. How would it be out of sections?

Comment: @JiosDev Use section number in your condition